# How do I set environment variables with bundle config that should be applied during a gem install?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm on an Apple m1 machine and ffi 1.11.3 won't build. I can install it if I use ffi that I install with homebrew though:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig" gem install ffi -v '1.11.3'
```

This works fine, but:

```
gem install -v '1.11.3'
```

Has this error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-print-multi-os-directory'
```

I know how to set flags that are used during an install of ffi with:

```
bundle config build.ffi "--some-flags"
```

but I can't figure out how to use this trick to set environment variables.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
BUNDLE_BUILD__FFI: "PKG_CONFIG_PATH=\"/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig\""
```

How do I set these variables? I'd also be happy to use the available flags to achieve the same thing, but I don't know how.

Comment: I do this way `bundle config --local build.nio4r --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"` to set cflags for `nio4r`

Comment: For your problem, you can try this `bundle config build.ffi --enable-system-libffi` Ref: https://github.com/ffi/ffi#requirements